# How I can add minutes in my current Date?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in my android app. I need to show a text after 10 minutes and i haven't any idea of how i can do.

I use a `Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();` and I wish to create a date higher than the current Date.

How I can add minutes in my current Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`add(int field, int value)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method.

Adding 10 minutes would be:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library make such work easy.

```
DateTime tenMinutesLater = DateTime.now().plusMinutes( 10 );
```

If you need a java.util.Date, convert from Joda-Time DateTime object.

```
java.util.Date date = tenMinutesLater.toDate();
```